# impl.ServerClient: Failed to find an available server in the list of servers:

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

I'm trying to query for testing a PC-server [JARVIS] (with Apache 1.7.0 Accumulation -Zookeper 3.4.6- Hadoop 2.7.1 on a PC with Ubuntu Server 14.04.3) with a Windows client PC [Casa-PC] (made in Eclipse where I carried out a project with maven libraries Accumulation-1.7.0 and hadoop-core-1.2.1) both on the same LAN.
When I try to interrogate the PC-server with the following code java run Eclipse on the PC-client brings me back the following listing:

> 15/11/30 07:14:31 WARN client.ClientConfiguration: Found no client.conf in default paths. Using default client configuration
>   values. 
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client
>   environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09
>   GMT 
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client
>   environment:host.name=Casa-PC 
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO
>   zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_60 
>   15/11/30
>   07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client
>   environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation 
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO
>   zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=... 
>   15/11/30
>   07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client
>   environment:java.class.path=... 
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO
>   zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=...;;.
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client
>   environment:java.io.tmpdir=... 
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO
>   zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler= 
>   15/11/30
>   07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Windows
>   7 15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client
>   environment:os.arch=x86 
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper:
>   Client environment:os.version=6.1 
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO
>   zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=... 
>   15/11/30
>   07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=...
>   15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client
>   environment:user.dir=... 15/11/30 07:14:32 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper:
>   Initiating client connection, connectString=JARVIS
>   sessionTimeout=30000
>   watcher=org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooSession$ZooWatcher@1ccaa
>   15/11/30 07:14:38 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection
>   to server JARVIS/192.168.1.104:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate
>   using SASL (unknown error) 15/11/30 07:14:38 INFO
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to
>   JARVIS/192.168.1.104:2181, initiating session 15/11/30 07:14:38 INFO
>   zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server
>   JARVIS/192.168.1.104:2181, sessionid = 0x15155768163000b, negotiated
>   timeout = 30000 
>   15/12/03 17:05:26 WARN rpc.ThriftUtil: Failed to open transport to
>   JARVIS:9997 
>   15/12/03 17:05:26 WARN impl.ServerClient: Failed to find
>   an available server in the list of servers: [JARVIS:9997 (120000)]
>   15/12/03 17:05:27 WARN rpc.ThriftUtil: Failed to open transport to
>   JARVIS:9997 
>   15/12/03 17:05:28 WARN rpc.ThriftUtil: Failed to open
>   transport to JARVIS:9997 
>   15/12/03 17:05:29 WARN rpc.ThriftUtil: Failed
>   to open transport to JARVIS:9997

```
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloException;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.AccumuloSecurityException;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.BatchWriter;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Connector;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Instance;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.TableExistsException;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.TableNotFoundException;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.ZooKeeperInstance;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.admin.TableOperations;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.security.tokens.KerberosToken;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Mutation;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.data.Value;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.security.ColumnVisibility;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;



public class Accumulo1 {

  public Connector connection;

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public static void main(String[] args)throws AccumuloException, AccumuloSecurityException, TableNotFoundException, TableExistsException, IOException {

    String instanceName = "instanceName ";
    String zooServers = "zooServers ";
    String userName = "userName ";
    String password = "password ";


    Instance inst = new ZooKeeperInstance(instanceName,zooServers);
    Connector connection = inst.getConnector(userName, password);

    BatchWriter bw = connection.createBatchWriter("demotable",1000000, 60000, 2);


    Text rowID = new Text("row1");
    Text colFam = new Text("colFam");
    Text colQual = new Text("colQual");

    ColumnVisibility colVis = new ColumnVisibility("public");
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Value value = new Value("some-value".getBytes());

    Mutation mutation = new Mutation(rowID);
    mutation.put(colFam, colQual, colVis, timestamp, value);

    bw.addMutation(mutation);

    bw.close();
  }

}
```

I checked the server and storage ('http://JARVIS:50095/servers') is present.
I can not understand what could be the problem.
Maybe I misconfigured Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

> There are no tablet servers: check that zookeeper and accumulo are running.

Make sure that you provided the correct zookeeper quorum string and Accumulo instance name. You should be able to get all of these from the Accumulo monitor `http://JARVIS:50095`. This means that, according to the properties you provided, Accumulo is not running.

This should also tell you if Accumulo is actually running -- look at the recent logs page for any Accumulo errors.

Comment: yes, I can go to http: // JARVIS: 50095 and i can see all you said 
In to logs errors reported are:
01/12/2015 21: 03: 57.805 tserver/master/gc/tracer: 270/271 JARVIS
WARN System swappiness setting is greater than ten (60) Which can cause time-sensitive operations to be delayed. Accumulation is time sensitive Because it needs to maintain distributed lock agreements.
The strings  instanceName is correct; zooServers is "JARVIS"; userName = "root"; and the password is root password used from accumulo to communicate with zookeeper.

Comment: Uh, Accumulo user mgmt (and passwords) have nothing to do with ZooKeeper. Try increasing the log level on your client to debug or trace and see if can you figure out what's happening. Sounds like Accumulo is just fine.

Comment: Thanks .. Can you suggest a few lines of code in the client to make the checks or recommend me some links where I can study them.

Comment: Use a debugger if you want to step through the client code, or, my recommendation, increase the Log4j logger level for the Accumulo core classes "org.apache.accumulo.core" to DEBUG or TRACE.

Comment: I should set in generic_logger.xml? What? In the manual isn't reported nothing. However there are news .. the problem now is different .. :-( –

Comment: No, this is *your* client. You should configure the log levels for Accumulo in your client application.